# C/C++ Linux, How to find neighbors on a network Without Using IP (MAC Only)

Tags: c++, c, linux, macos

In a small network, say 20 nodes or less, my program, on a test instrument, needs to know "Who is out there?" by MAC not by IP.    I will be plugging into random networks and need to be able to do this without having to know any addresses, MAC or otherwise in the network and knowing I can't rely on DHCP.  It is  completely reasonable that the DHCP server could be down and the nodes have no IP addresses and/or, I can't get one.  Truthfully, I don't need IP, our test protocol is MAC layer, not IP.

So, how can I determine my instrument's neighbor's MAC addresses?  This sounds a lot like LLDP but backwards, i.e., "who's out there", not "I'm here and I can do this...".  I must assume there is no IP assigned to the endpoints, so no ARPing, no NMAP, etc.

**Note** I should add, this is a wired network.

Comment: open up wireshark , catch all packets , look at all the source and destination mac address. in C++, open network interface in promiscuous mode, capture all packets, and parse to get source and destination mac address

Comment: And it's network topology?

Comment: @Vardhan  There may only be one other node (most likely case, actually).  What do I send out (broadcast? to get the other MAC to say things I can capture?  Or is there some MAC protocol that says all MACs say "hello" every now and then?

Comment: there are broadcast pings etc .. but some OS's may choose not to respond to broadcast .. as it's a security thingy..

Comment: This question was already answered here: http://serverfault.com/questions/245136/how-to-find-out-mac-addresses-of-all-machines-on-network

Comment: The question was not answered on the serverfault page @Pero provided, as the answers there involve using nmap or arp which are outside the scope of the question (OP said 'no IP'). The only relevant answer there was 'look at the switch', which is programable in the general case (i.e. requires knowledge of switch manufacturer  even if SNMP is being used, as well as switch topology).

Comment: @abligh, you are right. I did not read the question thorough enough. Thank you for letting us know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the general case, there is no MAC level protocol that you can send and guarantee a response from every machine on your network (I am assuming you are using ethernet here as I believe things are different on WLAN). IE there is no broadcast (or even, IIRC unicast) at the MAC layer that a host is guaranteed to respond to. With IP on top, you can IP broadcast and check the ARP cache.

The best way to do this would (in my opinion) be to use the way switches / learning bridges work on ethernet, i.e. passively listen in promiscuous mode for packets and note their MAC addresses. You won't spot completely silent hosts, but neither will a switch until a packet is sent by it. By definition there is no way to spot a completely silent host anyway.

Comment: +1 Now that's a godd, if unfortunate, answer.   Would you know of a packet sniffer I could copy and compile into the test instrument?  Using woreshark is a mite difficult with my development setup.  Too much MS Windows and too many VMs.

Comment: Sure. Use libpcap. And if it's a good answer, perhaps you want to accept it :-)

Comment: I'm prettty good about accepting answers.  I usually wait into the next day so I can give the  "night crew" a chance to answer.