# Automatic topology discovery in layer 2 with c on linux

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, network-protocols

I have a network applicaion running on several linux hosts connected by an ethernet LAN, consisting of just that hosts and some active ethernet switches (with MAC, VLAN, learning, SPT and everything but not IP stacks!).
MY application needs the knowledge of network topology. In fact each Host needs knowing what is the underlying connections between switches and Hosts.
I searched so far and here: [How to find neighbors on a network Without Using IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096480/c-c-linux-how-to-find-neighbors-on-a-network-without-using-ip-mac-only) 
in a situation very similar to my own the answer says that there is no way to do that. But here the difference is that all hosts are running my own software.

I'm courious whether that answer is valid in my case? Can I write an automatic topology discovery program in C?
Can I somehow read what switches learned from SPT?